# How to deny Googlebot only for a specific set of page variables?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I have a page that is `https://www.somedomain.com` and then under that page I have the option for users to change the language, like

```
https://www.somedomain.com/?change_language=en&random_id=123
https://www.somedomain.com/?change_language=de&random_id=123
https://www.somedomain.com/?change_language=fr&random_id=123
```

etc.

Is it possible to deny Googlebot from crawling these links, but still crawl the `https://www.somedomain.com/` main page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use robots.txt to target just the query parameter:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?change_language
```

This will prevent Google or other good bots from crawling the language options on the homepage. If you want to make it more universal to all pages:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: ?change_language
```

However, you might want to consider letting those language changes to be crawled and instead utilize the [`rel="alternate" hreflang` specification](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) that Google and Bing support.

This way you can indiciate to the engines that the content is in multiple languages allowing your site to get indexed in all the different country specific versions of Google, Bing, and Yahoo.